# How can I insert a " in a system.out.println statement?

Tags: java

I have to present this statement in Java output in the same way as it is shown below:

This is a test of your knowledge of "quotes" used in 'string literals.'

You're bound to "get it right" if you read the section on ''quotes.''

Comment: Did you read the section on quotes? Hint: Learn about escaping.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the escape character \ before the special character, in this case: quotes.

Would be like:

```
System.out.println("hello \"Escaped\" world");
```

It will be printed:

```
hello "Escaped" world
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two general ways to escape a literal ". Using a backslash like

```
String s = "\"Hello\"";
```

or using a `char` literal `'"'` like

```
String s = String.valueOf('"') + "Hello" + Character.toString('"');
```

Because unicode escapes are handled early you can't use a raw unicode double quote `\u0022` with-out escaping (again). That is

```
String s = "\\u0022Hello\\u0022";
```

is legal, but it isn't particularly readble. Once it's a `String` you can call

```
System.out.println(s);
```